# AJAX and a global variable not working, have I got this wrong?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

what I am trying to achieve is to AJAX a load of client's data into a page (this works), I then have a company ID in one of the fields brought in. I need to cross check this with a different company table (same database) to replace the company ID on the page with the name instead.

To get this I have set a global javascript variable to blank then fired off the main AJAX request getting all the initial client data then within that parsing loop (client side) I need to fire off a function which will check against the companies table to get the name. My current problem is that the global variable is not being set to the 2nd AJAX result. Here is my code:

```
var nameresult = "";

function namecheck(id){
var request = new Ajax().sendRequest
    ('../company_check.php',
        { method: 'GET',
          parameters: 'id=' + id,
          callback: namecheckReceived }
    );
}

function namecheckReceived(xmlHTTP){
      var n_data = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
      nameresult = n_data[0].name;
}

function client_call(){
var request = new Ajax().sendRequest
    ('../client_data.php',
        { method: 'GET',
          callback: searchReceived }
    );
}

function searchReceived(xmlHTTP){
      var data = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
      for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++)
          {
              namecheck(data[i].company_id);
             /////spit out all the data in a readable format //////
          }
}
```

Notes:

1. Only one result will be received from the company_check.php hence no
   loop in the namecheckRecieved() function.
2. No errors in the JS console.
3. The nameresult variable stays as blank and is never
   changed, if I alert(nameresult) within the namecheckRecieved()
   function it spits out what I want so why is it not changing the
   global variable with each loop of the searchRecieved() function?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. If you wait x seconds (or preferably access it in the success callback) your variable will become populated.

Comment: so populate the page with the company ID numbers then in successive callback replace the ID numbers with names?

Comment: No, move your `/////spit out all the data in a readable format //////` to the success callback and don't make `nameresult` global.

Comment: so create a new success callback if everything else is successful or do you mean the namecheckReceived()?

Comment: Look at it this way. You cannot access anything inside the success callback outside of the success callback. That isn't actually true, however if you think about it that way you won't have this problem.

Comment: hence the global variable which is being changed with each loop... so basically try and put the name check function inside the success callback?

Comment: Right, but `/////spit out all the data in a readable format //////` is happening long before the global var is being updated. the code continues to get processed, it doesn't wait for the ajax call to complete. What you end up with is sending off all the ajax requests at once, then after the loop finishes, the success callbacks start to fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to delete all my previous comment and say that you only need one ajax call. And everything should be done on server side. That means get the company Id, and use that to get the name of the company then pass everything back to the client side. From the look of it you are doing **A LOT** of call backs to the server to get every company name when you could have just done that on your first visit to the server. This way you do not need to worry about doing two ajax call ***Although from the look of it your doing more than 2 calls, depending on the length of data***

Comment: @Aaron check my response and tell me if it doable and make sense. Or if I am forgetting something.

Comment: The reason this is the right answer is that I needed to grab the companies names in the PHP script and just return the names no ID's. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'll take w/e I can get :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
     `function namecheckReceived(xmlHTTP){
      var n_data = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
      nameresult = n_data[0].name;
     client_call();
}`